# Rails app using googleAPI as login error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am following this paper step by step :https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails/
And I created a completely new rails app in order to test.
But I keep getting the same error: Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
 OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, 'CLIENT-ID', 'SECRET', {client_options: {ssl:
    {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
   get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
   get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
   resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
   resource :home, only: [:show]
   root to: "home#show"
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do 
|user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.save!
  end
end
```

end

ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    helper_method :current_user

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
end
```

SessionController.rb
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def create
         user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
         session[:user_id] = user.id
         redirect_to root_path
      end

```
  def destroy
     session[:user_id] = nil
     redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

Please help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541696/8120361) will only work if you also edit your system's /etc/hosts file to redirect 0.0.0.0 to a url ending with a non-raw address such as .com or .net, which is specifically what the error "message Raw IP addresses not allowed" is referring to.  If you do both of these things, your app should work in your development environment.

To do this, open /etc/hosts using your preferred text editor.  Since this is a protected system file, you will need to be in admin mode.  For example: `$ sudo vi /etc/hosts`.

Add the line to the bottom of the file:

```
0.0.0.0  my-custom-domain.com
```

Restart your shell session and your development server for the changes to take effect.

The custom redirect url ("my-custom-domain.com") will need to be authorized.  Go back to the Google Dev API Dashboard and add `http://my-custom-domain.com:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback` to your authorized redirect URIs.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your google dev API Dashboard you have to change the callback url to something other than `http://0.0.0.0...`

A workaround in a dev environment would be to change the callback url to `http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

[image: Google API Callback URL]

Comment: You may need to restart your rails server after updating. If that doesn't work please post the error message and any relevant files

Comment: restart server is not working... What files do you think might be helpful?

Comment: What does the error say? Please copy/paste the error code from the console

Comment: It is on top of the question:Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger